# Who would you like to become the new moderators?

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

If it was up to you who would like to become the new moderators?

The goal of this post is to motivate people who 
we think will be good moderators to nominate themselves.
Feel free to up-vote and edit the answers to add reasons 
why you think that person would be a good moderator.

Comment: We will have the election soon, this post is for motivating potential nominees not the election itself, please don't down-vote any answer.

Comment: Were Suresh, Kaveh, or Dave prepared to stand again, then they would probably all be good choices -- in my opinion, they have all shown themselves to be excellent moderators.

Comment: Don't the old moderators have to be re-elected again? Or is it a permanent position? It seems a bit odd if this is the case.

Comment: @Dilworth: Two of the old moderators are stepping down (perhaps only 1 if there are no more nominees). One (Suresh) will remain for reason of continuity.

Comment: @Dilworth, SE moderators normally stay as long as they are willing. But we think it is time to get some new moderators. Suresh also preferred to step down but we and SE requested from him to stay and help the new moderators get used to moderating.

Comment: I believe it would be much healthier if also the previous moderators are re-elected. If a moderator is re-elected it will serve as a sign for him or her of trust and support of his/her decisions and approach. If the moderator is not re-elected it is probably because the community is not satisfied with his/her performance or behavior.

Comment: @Dilworth, I agree that is healthier in that respect. However I don't think it is necessary to happen for all of them at once. In any case I think it was certain that Suresh would get the votes of almost all of active members of the community.

Comment: I'm not talking about a specific moderator. Obviously, Suresh is a great moderator. I think it would be better to re-elect all moderators, or at least to state when they are going to be re-elected if not now. Otherwise, e.g., there is no incentive for them to change their approach if perceived by many as inappropriate or controversial.

Comment: Moderation is not a popularity contest, a moderator may sometimes need to take actions which might not be completely popular (a moderator has access to information which might not be public or publicly discussable like user suspensions) however if you think a moderator is acting inappropriately you can bring it up on meta and in extreme cases directly contact SE (who can directly remove moderators in extreme cases). As I said I agree with you in principle to re-elect all moderators, but again as I wrote it does need to happen at the same time and there are good reasons for that.

Comment: If any one has a question about election process ask in the relevant thread by Grace. The nomination period has ended so adding new names does not make sense. I am locking this to stop it's abuse.

Answer (score 10):

### [Sasho Nikolov](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/4896/sasho-nikolov)

Answer (score 9):

### [Lev Reyzin](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/123/lev-reyzin)

Answer (score 8):

### [Andrej Bauer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/705/andrej-bauer)

Answer (score 7):

### [Neel Krishnaswami](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/657/neel-krishnaswami)

Comment: Since Dave has decided to step down it would be nice to have a new moderator from theory B to replace him.

Comment: I was thinking of nominating Neel.

Comment: @Dave, now you have to nominate another person from theory B in addition to Neel. :)

Answer (score 6):

### [David Richerby](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/17082/david-richerby)

Suresh: I would nominate [David Richerby](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/17082/david-richerby). Lots of activity, especially relating to "meta" level concerns.

Answer (score 6):

### [Marzio De Biasi](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/3247/marzio-de-biasi)

Answer (score 1):

### [Aaron Sterling](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/30/aaron-sterling)